# Transaction fails

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I got some method:

```
public SaveMyData(...)
{
    var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Snapshot };
            using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions))
            {
                var dataInDb = dbDataService.LoadData();

                dataInDb.SomeField = someNewValue;

                dbDataService.SaveData(dataInDb);

                transactionScope.Complete();             
            }
}
```

So it takes string serialized Dto from database and changes field. Than save it.

`SaveMyData` can be called from different threads in same time, so i got error:

> You cannot use snapshot isolation to access table 'some table'
>   directly or indirectly in database 'some db' to update, delete, or
>   insert the row that has been modified or deleted by another
>   transaction. Retry the transaction or change the isolation level for
>   the update/delete statement

How can i avoid this error? I need to use different isolation level?

Inside `SaveData()` method i create new EF context and save changes.

The way i want to make it work is:
`CallerA` call `SaveMyData`, it locks and if `CallerB` calls it in same time he will wait untill `CallerA` commit. So i need to not allow `CallerB` read data before `CallerA` write changes.

Comment: The error explains what's going on. Some other code modified the records while `SaveMyData` run. Snapshot isolation mean you don't block when trying to read records that others may be updating. You *still* can't modify them if they've been modified by another transaction

Comment: Just like optimistic concurrency, you have to decide what to do. Retry and lose the changes made by someone else? Stop and warn the user? Read the new objects and merge them in code with your own?

Comment: What happens in the `SaveData` function? Is there another transaction? And where is your DataContext initialized? Could it be, that someone else changes the entity while you are executing the code?

Comment: I make some edits, check please.

Comment: If you want locks and waiting, then don't use snapshot isolation, as it's the exact opposite of that. Use `Serializable` to make updates fully independent.